# How to read the JSON file from the API in the interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to read a JSON file  from the API every 11 seconds and display it in the interface
In my case :
the interface server is running at http://localhost:8080/
the API at http://localhost:8088/route (and I need to refresh it every 11 seconds because parameters changes)

and in route.js :

```
var i=0;
var delayInms = 11000; 

var myVar = setInterval(TempFunction, 1000);
function TempFunction() {

router.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    var text =[
        {"carspeed":[233+i,445+i,223+i,444+i,234+i]},
       
    ]
       console.log(text);
       res.status(200).json(text);
        });
        window.location.reload(true);
         i++;

    }
```

********THE PROBLEM is that I get this error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

I have another question :
to read the JSON (which is updated in http://localhost:8088/route every 11 seconds) I did this :
in car.vue :

```
<template>
.
.
<ul>
<li v-for="todo of todos" :key="todo.id">{{todo.text}}</li>
</ul>
.
.
</template>
```

followed by :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
const WorkersURL="http://localhost:8088/route";

export default {
  data: () => ({
  drawer: false,
  todos:[]

}),
async created()
{
  try
 {
  const res = await axios.get(WorkersURL);
  this.todos=res.data;
 }
catch(e)
{
 console.error(e)
}

  }
}
<script>
```

********AND THE SECOND PROBLEM : it doesn't read the JSON file from http://localhost:8088/route

Comment: `it doesn't read the JSON file from ....` where does it read it from? or are you getting a CORS error?

Comment: You're confusing client and server side. There's no window in Node and you cannot refresh browser page from there. setInterval should be called on client side, and refreshing a page with window.location would be a mistake, refresh relevant data with Vue reactivity.

Comment: Bad idea to implement it your way

Comment: in API ,when I go to  http://localhost:8088/route I see the JSON , and when I refresh I see the updated data(because in route.js I change data every 11 seconds) , but I want to recover this JSON every 11 seconds in the client side, and  that why I want to refrech the server side every 11 seconds(so that I'll recover the refreshed JSON and display it in the page every 11 seconds) .. I don't know if it is is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that you are enabling your server to be hit from web pages running at a different host/domain/port. In your case, the server is running on a different port than the webpage itself, so you can't make XHR (which is what Axios is doing) calls successfully because CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is not enabled by default. Your server will need to set the appropriate headers to allow that. Specifically, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Second, to update your client every 11 seconds there are a few choices. The simplest would be to make you call via axios every 11 seconds using setInterval:

```
 async created()
{
  try
 {
  const res = await axios.get(WorkersURL);
  this.todos=res.data;
   // set a timer to do this again every 11 seconds
   setInterval(() => {
     axios.get(WorkersURL).then((res) => {
      this.todos=res.data;
    });
   }, 11000);
 }
catch(e)
{
 console.error(e)
}

  }
```

There are a couple of options that are more advanced such as serve-sent events (See https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/tree/master/server-sent-events) or websockets (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). Both of these options allow you to control the interval on the server instead of the client. There are some things to consider when setting up your server for this, so the `setInterval` options is probably best in your case.

Comment: Do you mean that I should make this server route listen to (http://localhost:8080/route) in which the interface is running(and use it as WorkersURL in my case)? Thanks

Comment: That's one way to solve it. If both are running on the same host/domain/port, then you don't need to worry about CORS. But in many cases, it is common to have a microservice running on a different server, so learning how to deal with CORS is vauable too. Without knowing exactly the full scope of what you are doing, it is hard to make a recommendation as to what is best.